# Format code on Build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coding-style, formatting

I'm working on a group project, and we've been having some merge conflicts. We have a convention to use tabs instead of spaces, but spaces keep leaking in, causing what KDiff calls "whitespace conflicts." Visual Studio, which we're all using, allows us to choose tabs over spaces and even tabify documents, but I'm looking for an elegant solution.

- Is there a way to run a script on build that formats code?
- Or, is there a way to tabify all documents at once?

I'm just assuming script here, I'm very open to anything that would keep this code formatted

Answer (score 1):

[JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx) have a beatify command with different profiles, which allows you to set what exactly should be beatified. It can be run on a single file, project or the whole solution. I don't think that it could be set to run on build, though.

Comment: That's really cool, but I was hoping not to buy another development tool.